# Angular Cannot Read Property of Undefined Loop Through Array

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to iterate through an Array infinitely with a 4 second interval. It's executing the function every 4 seconds but I'm getting the following logged in the console:

- wemadeit
- undefined
- ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'undefined' of undefined

```
export class TechnologiesComponent implements OnInit {

  public slideInState: String = 'in';

  public test1Show: Boolean = true;
  public test2Show: Boolean = false;

  private counter: number = 0;
  private imgArray: Array<boolean> = [false, false, false, false];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    setInterval(this.imgCycle, 4000);
  }

  imgCycle() {
    console.log('wemadeit')
    console.log(this.counter)
    console.log(this.imgArray[this.counter])
    this.imgArray[this.counter] = true;
    if (this.counter == this.imgArray.length) {
      this.counter = 0
      console.log('reset')
    } else {
      this.counter++
      console.log('+1')
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`imgCycle` method is running outside Angular's zone as setInterval is a browser api. Changing it to an arrow method will solve this issue. Example:

```
imgCycle = () => {
    console.log('wemadeit')
    console.log(this.counter)
    console.log(this.imgArray[this.counter])
    this.imgArray[this.counter] = true;
    if (this.counter == this.imgArray.length) {
      this.counter = 0
      console.log('reset')
    } else {
      this.counter++
      console.log('+1')
    }
  }
```

Comment: Actually, there is not direct Angular documentation for this since it has to do with two things: 1. How arrow functions work (similar to closures i.e. there maintain the reference to the block they were declared in) and 2. Triggers for Angular's change detection  (network or user activity). https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html

Answer (score 0):

This is not specifically an angular issue. Your **`this` is not actually `this`**. The context when you run `setTimeout` is different. When you are running `setTimeout`, you are actually running `window.setTimeout()` so when you are referring to `this` you are actually referencing to `window` object. Which won't be having a `imgCycle()` method. There are few ways to fix this issue.

**1. Using `bind()`:**

```
ngOnInit() {
   setInterval(this.imgCycle.bind(this), 4000);
}

imgCycle() {}
```

**2. Using arrow functions :**

This will need you to change your `imgCycle` into a method variable

```
ngOnInit() {
   setInterval(this.imgCycle, 4000);
}

imgCycle = () => {};
```